# Faster way of Downloading Metadata in CSV

Tags: powershell, excel, metadata, download, csv

we Have document library with 3lacs+ items. we have to download metadata of each file in a csv such as Modified date , modified By etc. I used powershell code for achieving this task but for some reasons , it doesn't populate all the fields properly. so I switched for using datasheet view with filters and than open it in excel. But it takes long time because of the size. do we have any other option to do it fast and more accurately?.

Answer (score 0):

Under "Library Tools", you have "Export to Excel", then you can filter this Excel and save it to .csv